# Ripple rejection of 7805 voltage regulator

Tags: integrated-circuit, datasheet

In the last row of the picture  of the data sheet of 7805 voltage regulator, the ripple reduction ranges from 62 to 78 dB for the voltage range of 8 to 18 volts at 120 Hz.

Is it the range of input voltage?

From this data sheet, how can I calculate the ripple reduction ratio for let's say 12 volts 60 Hz and 12 volts 100 Hz?

[image]

[Source](https://www.digikey.com/en/htmldatasheets/production/28194/0/0/1/ua7805ckcs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it the range of input voltage?

Yes, the "I" in V<sub>I</sub> is for "input".

(also, what other voltage would that describe? The output voltage by definition never gets that high; it's nominally 5 V.)

> From this data sheet how can I calculate the ripple reduction ratio for let's say 12 volts 60 Hz and 12 volts 100 Hz?

No, that makes no sense; your voltage needs to be > 5V at any point in time, so it can't be a pure AC voltage. You will need to do like the datasheet does, and define a minimum offset voltage, to which you can add a harmonic oscillation, for that spec to make sense.

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph: I assume he does not mean a pure 12V 60 Hz AC input, but the PSRR at 60Hz, when DC input is around 12V.

Comment: OK but how can I find the ripple reduction at 12 volts at the same 120 Hz frequency?

Comment: @Alex Datasheet says it already. 12V is within 8V to 18V range.

Comment: OK but what exactly will be the ripple reduction for 12 volts according to the data sheet? Will it be 62 dB?

Comment: Does this data sheet says that the ripples reduction is 62 dB for the range of 8 to 18 volts?

Comment: @Alex seriously. It's in the table. You will need to read the table as it is explicitly stated:  We will not waste time repeating what is written in the table. Please specify **exactly** what you don't understand about the table, and we can help explain how to read the table.

Comment: Really I am not understanding what is the ripple reduction for 12 volts input. Range is given but I am confused about it. Infact that is the first time in my life that I am reading a data sheet.

Comment: so, yeah, the ripple suppression is in the specified range. Can you put into words what is unclear? I'm really confused.

Comment: I am confused that what will be the exact ripple suppression for 12 volt input from the range of 62 to 78 dB?

Comment: @Alex Ripple suppression will be at least 62 dB and typically 78dB. That is what the minimum and typical values in the table mean. If there's a max then it would be less than that value, although no max is given.

Comment: @Alex no exact suppression is specified. The datasheet specifies a range. What would anyone need the *exact* suppression for, anyways? You always need to know "what's the worst case I need to deal with" when it comes to noise.

Comment: @Alex I mean, do you understand what it means for a 12 V variation to be suppressed by 62 dB? What about by 70 dB? Ask yourself for which part of your design that is relevant, and then ask yourself whether the datasheet specifies what you need to know.

Comment: Thanks Marcus I understand it now.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, \$V_I\$ means Input voltage, so the last row specifies the parameter (that we can't see, but probably is the PSRR) for an input voltage between 8 and 18V.

To get the ripple reducation for other frquencies this information is pretty useless, the PSRR might be constant over a wide range or it might break completly down for frequencies only slightly above the specified one.
To get information about PSRR at other frequencies search for plots of PSRR vs f, like this one here:
[image]

Comment: OK but how can I find the ripple reduction at 12 volts at the same 120 Hz frequency?

Comment: It might help if you could share a link to your exact datasheet ;)

Comment: I am confused that what will be the exact ripple suppression for 12 volt input from the range of 62 to 78 dB?

Comment: @Alex Ripple rejection ratio doesn't depend significantly on voltage.

Answer (score 0):

> In the last row of the picture of the data sheet of 7805 ic voltage regulator ripple reduction ranges from 62 to 78 dB for the voltage range of 8 to 18 volts at 120 Hz.
>
> Is it the range of input voltage?

If the input DC voltage is at least 8 V and less than 18 V, then you will get *at least*, that is, a guarranteed, 68 dB suppression of the input ripple at 120 Hz - that is the ripple frequency you'll get from a full wave rectifier from 60 Hz AC. Typically though, you might hope for the typical 78 dB.

This 68 dB to 78 dB is not a range as such, only the 68 dB means anything if you are designing to a specification, professionally. If you are hobbyist, then hope to get 78 dB, but don't bank on it. You might get more than 78 dB.

> From this data sheet how can I calculate the ripple reduction ratio for let's say 12 volts 60 Hz and 12 volts 100 Hz?

If there's a graph of PSRR versus frequency in the datasheet, then you can estimate how the typicals vary with frequency. If there isn't , you might expect the rejection to be reasonably flat over the 50/60/100/120 Hz range, which will give you the right ballpark.